# Ember.js open a websocket

Tags: ember.js, websocket

I'm new with ember.js and i'm trying to open a websocket client to receive data in real time from a server.
but, i have no idea how to do that ! i found this link https://www.npmjs.org/package/ember-sockets but it's not clear ! 
Someone has an idea?

Comment: What part of ember-sockets isn't clear?  I'm currently using that library and it works pretty well so I can probably help out if you have a more specific question about it.

Comment: right now i'm trying to open a websocket client with ember , i found this code 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22459010/emberjs-and-websocket-best-approach
but the function connect does not work 

    var socket = window.io.connect('http://localhost:8080'); 

this is the error:
Error while loading route: TypeError: Cannot read property 'connect' of undefined
Do you have an idea?

Comment: Have you included the socket.io client in your project? https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-client  Socket.IO requires a server and client component to work.

Comment: no i didn't ! when i added <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script> it print this error : GET file:///C:/socket.io/socket.io.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND  should i install or add something ? i found npm install socket.io but the problem i'm working on windows

Comment: Are you serving your website off of a node.js server or trying to make it work without a web server?  The fact that it's looking for socket.io.js using a file path makes me think you're not actually hosting your code using the node web server.  You should probably use something like express http://expressjs.com/ to get a web server up and running quickly and just serve up your website using the `static` middleware `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));`